# Rails - Join Table with Attributes (HABTM + Through) But how do I create / delete records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, has-many-through

I have a User model and Interest Model being joined by a join table called Choice (details below). I'm using the HABTM relationship with through since I have an attribute within the join table as well.

User.rb

```
has_many :choices
has_many :interests, :through => :choices
```

Interest.rb

```
has_many :choices
has_many :users, :through => :choices
```

Choice.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :interest
```

So the question is how do I add records to this newly created choice table. For example =>

```
@user = User.find(1)
@interest = Interest.find(1)
?????   Choice << user.id + interest.id + 4(score attribute) ??????
```

The last part is the part I'm having a problem with..I have these 3 parameters and didn't how to add them in and what the syntax was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options for adding a choice, but what probably makes the most sense would be to add choices by scoping to the user instance:

Assuming:

```
@user = User.find(1)
@interest = Interest.find(1)
```

You could add a choice like so:

```
@user.choices.create(:interest => @interest, :score => 4)
```

You could also do something like this in your controller:

```
def create
  @choice = @user.choices.build(params[:choice])

  if @choice.save
    # saved
  else
    # not saved
  end
end
```

**This assumes your form has fields for `choice[:interest_id]` and `choice[:score]`**

Comment: Is there anyway to check to see if the record has been added first and update if thats the case?

Comment: There probably is, but you might want to consider providing a RESTful interface for managing choices. Each Choice would have an edit/update UI where the user could manage each choice individually. Once you have this down, you could add some JS for an edit in place type of interface.